# How can I reference a local Mercurial repository in Maven if it is two directories up?

Tags: maven, mercurial

We have been using SCM URLs in POM files like this:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:hg:file:///${basedir}</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:hg:file:///${basedir}</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

It requires us to start the release process with a "mvn release:prepare -DpushChanges=false", but we had to do that anyway (the hg plugin doesn't handle authentication correctly). The big plus for us is that we can "hg strip" if the release process goes wrong at any point -- no one but the local developers will ever see that.

The same process works if we have a directory inside a Mercurial checkout. In that case the following URLs do the trick:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:hg:file:///${basedir}/..</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:hg:file:///${basedir}/..</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

But: it all goes wrong when there's another level in there. I have tried a number of variations of the file URL, but they all seem to fail.

The naive approach of using "scm:hg:file:///${basedir}/../.." causes both the site plugin as well as the release plugin to fail. The former will tell me this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.2:site (default-site) on project epik-protocol-spec: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.2:site failed: This SCM url 'scm:hg:file:///../epik-protocol-spec' is invalid due to the following errors:
[ERROR] * An hg 'file' url must be on the form 'file:///' or 'file://localhost/'.
[ERROR] For more information about SCM URL Format, please refer to: http://maven.apache.org/scm/scm-url-format.html
```

('epik-protocol-spec' is the name of a module in the build that is running)

The release plugin encounters a similar issue: after a release:prepare the release.properties file will have the scm.url set to "file:///..", which will then fail to get a copy of the tagged code during release:perform. The workaround for this is to fix the property manually between the steps. I haven't found a way to make the site build work, yet.

My goals are:

- have a build that just works out of the box (i.e. clone the project from IDE and run any target)
- be able to generate the site (and run other builds) on a build server
- be able to run releases with the release plugin, with all changes being reviewed before pushing

Has anyone a solution for this? And why do the URLs get mangled so badly -- is the approach bad or are we encountering a Maven problem?

### Edit

As proposed by Charlee, I checked the output of mvn help:effective-pom. The SCM URLs are mangled in that. It also shows that Maven appends module names to the URLs, which means it will be necessary to define the URLs on each module -- assuming that the odd mangling can be stopped.

A custom property like this:

```
<properties>
    <test.property>scm:hg:file:///${basedir}/../..</test.property>
</properties>
```

does not get mangled, it gets resolved as expected (also checked using the effective POM).

Comment: Reading the source of AbstractSvmManager.java I can see why the HG provider raises the error: the URL is shortened before passing into the provider itself, which means the "//../" part will end as "/", i.e. the URL going into the HG provider is "file://epik-protocol-spec". That doesn't explain why the ${basedir} isn't resolved properly, though.

Answer (score 1):

The Maven SCM provider is shortening URLs based on a "../" and "..\" matching scheme. If one of these character sequences is matched, it will search backwards for a matching slash (past the one just prior), removing everything back to that. This rule meant that my file URLs, which would look something like this:

```
scm:hg:file:///C:\some\local\path/../..
```

would trigger the shortening due to the "../" sequence, it would then delete back to the previous *forward* slash, which means back to the slash before the "C:", thus deleting the whole path.

This behaviour is not triggered if there's no slash behind the dots, so the step up at the end of my URLs caused no harm -- which explains why I had no issues with going up one level.

The solution (workaround?) is to use this:

```
scm:hg:file:///${basedir}${file.separator}..${file.separator}..
```

Then the URL shortening will encounter matching slashes no matter the OS and it starts to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the [SCM Implementation: Mercurial](http://maven.apache.org/scm/mercurial.html), it mentions at the example as the following: -

```
scm:hg:http://host/v3
scm:hg:file://C:/dev/project/v3 (windows drive) 
              <--- only 2 slashes + [os, e.g. drive:/path/...]
scm:hg:file:///home/smorgrav/dev/project/v3 (linux drive) 
              <--- only 2 slashes + [os, e.g. /home/...]
scm:hg:/home/smorgrav/dev/project/v3 (local directory)
```

Anyhow the Maven told us as

```
This SCM url 'scm:hg:file:///../epik-protocol-spec' 
is invalid due to the following errors
```

Please correct me, if I'm wrong. I understand that you're in the Microsoft Windows environment and may use only 2 slashes for achieving your requirement.

Anyhow the another suspected may be the `${basedir}` is resolved as `../epik-protocol-spec`. If I understand correctly, it should be a full path instead.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Interesting thought with the double slashes. It doesn't work, but it produces an interesting change. Maven complains "This SCM url 'scm:hg:file://..' is invalid" afterwards. No more module name. And yes: I would have expected an absolute path as well.

Comment: Could you please provide the `mvn help:effective-pom` result? There may be some significant about the resolved `<scm>...</scm>`.

Comment: The effective POM is more than 2000 lines long, let me just describe the SCM results. For the parent the "scm:hg:file:///${basedir}/../.." in the original POM gets changed to "scm:hg:file:///.." (i.e. no absolute path and we lose one level of going up. Both not what I expected. The modules get resolved to "scm:hg:file:///../$MODULE_NAME". I can see how the latter makes sense for something like Subversion, but it's not a good idea for Mercurial. That latter problem I could probably avoid by configuring separate URLs for the modules, but that would just lead back to problem A.

Comment: BTW: there is http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-508 on the question of how many slashes, but I believe triple slashing is correct. Two are for the end of the scheme part, the third denotes the fact that the host is omitted (defaulting to localhost). Even Windows explorer agrees: "file:///c:\temp" entered in the location works, "file://c:\temp" triggers an error.